# Can you use Partitioned Memory from DSG then use The Look and Walls of Jericho

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Could a demon use "Partitioned Memory" in turn 1. -from DSG
--Partitioned Memory allows the demon to perform two mental actions.

Then use "The Look" on the same turn as using "Walls of Jericho"? -both from FoH
--The Look - Vocal embed / --Walls of Jericho - Exploit

I would think so as the TL and WoJ don't require any physical movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [Can a Demon manifest 2 embeds while using the Partitioned Memory Embed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105013/can-a-demon-manifest-2-embeds-while-using-the-partitioned-memory-embed), this is a bit more of a gray area in terms of the rules.

As such, I don't have any book references, and I have no personal experience STing this in a game.

However, as a personal call, I would say yes, because their effects aren't stacking. The immobilized person can't benefit from cover; and the people having cover taken away aren't immobilized.

Your ST (or you, as an ST) may well disagree.